# Kivy outside rule inherence

Tags: python, kivy

I want to specify a special button so I don't have to adjust every button I use, however I want it's event to trigger a function in a different class.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class FancyButton(Button):
    imp = ObjectProperty(None)


class Important(StackLayout):

    def NoInspiration(self, smile):
        print("Received: {}".format(smile))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

test.kv (working)

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<FancyButton@Button>:
    on_release: self.parent.NoInspiration(':)')


<Important>:
    id: imp

    FancyButton:
        text: "smiley"

BoxLayout:
    Important
```

> Received: :)

test.kv (**not** working)

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<FancyButton>:
    on_release: self.parent.NoInspiration(':)')


<Important>:
    id: imp

    BoxLayout:
        FancyButton:
            text: "smiley"

BoxLayout:
    Important
```

In the 2nd test.kv I added 'BoxLayout:' in front of FancyButton and suddenly I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'BoxLayout' object has no attribute 'NoInspiration'

### Question

- Why does self.parent only refer to the direct parent and not < Important > in the 2nd example?
- How can I have on_release: in < FancyButton > point to the function NoInspiration() while keeping the function in < Important >?

### Follow up questions

- [Kivy rule inherence with add_widget()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621302/kivy-rule-inherence-with-add-widget)
- [Kivy outside rule inherence 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626223/kivy-outside-rule-inherence-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the kv to this

```
<FancyButton>:
    on_release: self.imp.NoInspiration(':)')


<Important>:
    id: imp

    BoxLayout:
        FancyButton:
            text: "smiley"
            imp: root

BoxLayout:
    Important
```