# Kivy rule inherence with add_widget()

Tags: python, kivy

Follow up question: [Kivy outside rule inherence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618565/kivy-outside-rule-inherence)

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.factory import Factory


class FancyButton(Button):
    imp = ObjectProperty(None)


class Important(StackLayout):

    def NoInspiration(self, smile):
        print("Received: {}".format(smile))

    def AddFancy(self):
        temp = Factory.FancyButton(text='f', imp = self.ids.imp)
        self.ids.boxy.add_widget(temp)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.9.0
#:import App kivy.app

<FancyButton>:
    on_release: self.imp.NoInspiration(':)')


<Important>:
    id: imp

    BoxLayout:
        id: boxy
        orientation: 'vertical'

        FancyButton:
            text: "smiley"
            imp: root

        Button:
            text: "add fancy"
            on_release: imp.AddFancy()


BoxLayout:
    Important
```

In test.kv the function call in FancyButton to the function NoInspiration() works, because the FancyButton defined in the .kv has imp: root, so it knows it should look for the function in < Important >:.

### Question

However how does imp: root work when you create FancyButton through add_widget in Python?

Now when I press the button "add fancy" I get the error:

> File "main.py", line 18, in AddFancy
>        temp = Factory.FancyButton(text='f', imp = self.ids.imp)
>      File "properties.pyx", line 756, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr __ (kivy/properties.c:11093)
>    AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr __'

### Follow up Question

[Kivy outside rule inherence 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626223/kivy-outside-rule-inherence-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Widget.ids` only contain ids of its children (http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.ids. Id of the widget itself it's not needed because you can just pass it directly - in your case using `self`, since you're passing a reference to a widget from inside of a method:

```
class Important(StackLayout):
    def NoInspiration(self, smile):
        print("Received: {}".format(smile))

    def AddFancy(self):
        print(self.ids) # only returns {'boxy': <weakproxy at 0000000002D119A8 to BoxLayout at 0000000002D026A8>}
        self.ids.boxy.add_widget(FancyButton(text='f', imp = self)) # no need to use a factory
```

Comment: Thanks it worked :) Could you also take a look at the Follow up question?