# Kivy outside rule inherence 2

Tags: python, kivy

As follow-up question to:

- [Kivy outside rule inherence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618565/kivy-outside-rule-inherence)
- [Kivy rule inherence with add_widget()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621302/kivy-rule-inherence-with-add-widget/31625031#31625031)

main.py

```
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class FancyButton(Button):
    imp = ObjectProperty(None)


class Important(StackLayout):

    font_kanji = os.path.join('fonts', 'TakaoPMincho.ttf')

    def NoInspiration(self, smile):
        print("Received: {}".format(smile))

    def AddFancy(self):
        print(self.ids)
        temp = FancyButton(text='f', imp = self)
        self.ids.boxy.add_widget(temp)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<FancyButton>:
    font_name: self.imp.font_kanji  # ERROR
    on_release: self.imp.NoInspiration(':)')  # WORKS


<Important>:
    id: imp

    BoxLayout:
        id: boxy
        orientation: 'vertical'

        FancyButton:
            text: "smiley"
            imp: root

        Button:
            text: "add fancy"
            on_release: imp.AddFancy()


BoxLayout:
    Important
```

In the above example 'on_release: self.imp.NoInspiration(':)')' works because FancyButton has 'imp: root'.

However 'font_name: self.imp.font_kanji' doesn't work and gives the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'font_kanji'

My guess is the reason for this is that on_release takes place after all widgets are loaded and font_name directly, so without having 'imp: root'.

I also tried:

```
font_kanji = StringProperty(os.path.join('fonts', 'TakaoPMincho.ttf'))
```

, but to no avail.

### Question

How do I get font_name refer to font_kanji? Should I use global? If yes, how would you set a global in Python which can be accessed in the .kv?

(If I put global in front of font_Kanji and remove 'self.imp' in the .kv file I get the error: " NameError: name 'font_kanji' is not defined")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is right: when your button is created its `imp` property is `None`. One to go around this would be to observe `imp` property and set the value of `font_name` in its handler:

```
class FancyButton(Button):
    imp = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_imp(self, obj, imp):
        if imp:
            self.font_name = imp.font_kanji
```

This way the font is set after `imp` property is initialzied with proper `Important` instance. The dissadvantage of this method is that changes of `Instance.font_kanji` won't trigger changes of `FancyButton.font_name`.

If you want to have both properties binded, then you have to call `bind` funtion from `Instance.font_kanji` side (since we want to react to its changes) for dynamically created `FancyButton` instances:

```
class Important(StackLayout):
    font_kanji = os.path.join('fonts', 'TakaoPMincho.ttf')

    def NoInspiration(self, smile):
        print("Received: {}".format(smile))

    def AddFancy(self):
        temp = FancyButton(text='f', imp = self)
        self.bind(font_kanji=temp.setter('font_name'))
        self.ids.boxy.add_widget(temp)
```

Interface defined in the kv language can do the binding directly:

```
<Important>:
    id: imp

    BoxLayout:
        id: boxy
        orientation: 'vertical'

        FancyButton:
            text: "smiley"
            font_name: root.font_kanji
            imp: root

        Button:
            text: "add fancy"
            on_release: imp.AddFancy()
''')
```

Comment: This works for the font which I don't have to change after runtime :). However it would still be interesting for future reference to know if it was the case that font_name should change depending on imp.font_kanji. Would that be possible with bind() somehow?